# How to immediately show an instance of InAppBrowser, when a controller loads, without the Ionic app becoming unresponsive?

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

I am using Ionic 1.2.4. I am immediately showing an InAppBrowser (https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) via an Angular controller. I have also setup the controller to respond to taps on the page by again showing an InAppBrowser.

The initial appearance of the InAppBrowser works correctly. However, once the user taps "Done" and then taps on the revealed page, the subsequent InAppBrowser is not displayed. In addition to this it appears that the app stops responding to further gestures (the page is setup to display the number of touch gestures it has detected).

I have confirmed that there is no issue with the code that presents the InAppBrowser on taps by testing without the immediate InAppBrowser display. This results in an app where the user can indefinitely display and dismiss the InAppBrowser (and where the number of touches is correctly displayed on the page).

I have a demo of the issue here: https://github.com/ryanggrey/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser-issue. This shows all my code and dependency versions (see package.json and bower.json). `touch.js` is where all the above mentioned code can be found.

I'm guessing I've either found a bug in `cordova-plugin-inappbrowser`, or I'm using the API incorrectly. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is due to the inappbrowser plugin added from Cordova as some some code are missing in it. Remove the plugin and try adding it from

-
 cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git

Hope it will work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. What do you mean by "some code are missing in it"? I originally added the plugin as per https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser#installation and specified version 1.2.1.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, but it doesn't seem to help.